# Bitbucket-pipelines to circleCI translation

Tags: circleci, bitbucket-pipelines

How can I proceed to build different things depending on the branch on circleCI?
Could you help me to translate this bitbucket-pipelines.yml to circleCI.yml?

```
   image: atlassian/default-image:2

   pipelines:
      default:
        - step:
      script:
        - ant -buildfile build/build.xml banner
   branches:
      master:
       - step:
           script:
               - Deploy to PRO 

      develop:
       - step:
           script:
              - echo "Deploy to sandbox"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This guide](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/workflows/#branch-level-job-execution) explains configuring branch based workflows in CircleCI.

Essentially you define branch filters for each job to determine whether they should run.

This can be combined with [reusable jobs](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/reusing-config/#authoring-parameterized-jobs) to avoid repetition for common sandbox/prod tasks.

```
version: 2.1

workflows:
  build-deploy:
    jobs:
      - say_hello:
          to_whom: sandbox
      - say_hello:
          to_whom: prod
          filters:
            branches:
              only: master

jobs:
  say_hello:
    parameters:
      to_whom:
        type: string
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:10
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: ant -buildfile build/build.xml banner
      - run: echo "hello <<parameters.to_whom>>"
```